# Stop program from crashing when entering not-numbers in a menu with numbered options

Tags: haskell

My search function works properly when the input is a number, but crashes when it is not. What can I add to my code to prevent that from happening?

```
searchAge = do
  putStrLn "\n Please type the age of the person you're looking for: \n"
  age <- getLine
  input <- readFile $ "databas.txt"
  putStrLn "\n Here are all the people that matches your search: \n"
  let people = parse input
      output = map personToString (filter (\p -> personAge p == read age) people)
    in putStrLn (unlines output)

putStrLn "Let's get back to the search menu again!"     
searchDatabase
```

Comment: It would kinda help if you showed us how you approached the problem so far, i.e., code please...

Comment: Blind guessing: replace `read` with `readMaybe`, and handle the error case (`import Text.Read` first). You should really provide more information in your question.

Comment: Listen up, oh younger one,  /
as this is a maddening song. /  
Take a look and you will see  /
`read :: String -> Int` is wrong for ye. / It's type is wrong, it's result is unknown / if you use it on a random string like `"frown"`. / But here is for a final hint / you're looking for `readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int`.

Comment: lol ... there should be a platinum badge for answers/comments like this ... **yo**

Comment: @Zeta, why isn't that an answer?

Comment: @dfeuer: Because I also wanted to improve the question's quality, but didn't have the time yesterday.

Comment: @Carsten Time for a new challenge: Write at least one answer per week as a poem.

Comment: The indentation doesn't really make sense. Please *add* any that you need.

Comment: @Carsten: Second week, [second poem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35733380/1139697) :D.

Answer (score 15):

Listen up, oh younger one,
as this is a maddening song.
Take a look and you will see
`read :: String -> Int` is wrong for ye.

Its type is wrong, its result is unknown;
if been used on a string like `"frown"`.
But here is for the final hint
you're looking for [`readMaybe :: String -> Maybe Int`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe).

---

The problem with `read` is that there is no notion of failure in its type signature:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

What happens if we set `a` to `Int` and try to use it on the string `"frown"`? It will result in an exception:

```
ghci> read "frown" :: Int
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

After all, what should it return? Anything from the domain of `Int` is a valid value.

Enter `readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`. Now the potential error is covered in the type signature, and it does not result in an exception anymore:

```
ghci> import Text.Read
ghci> readMaybe "frown" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
ghci> readMaybe "15" :: Maybe Int
Just 15
```

We can wrap this in a new function called `getNumber` that repeatedly asks for an `Int` until the user actually provides one:

```
getNumber :: IO Int
getNumber = do
  line <- getLine
  case (readMaybe line :: Maybe Int) of
     Just x  -> return x
     Nothing -> putStrLn "Please enter a number!" >> getNumber
```

You can then use it to get an `Int` instead of a `String` for your `age`:

```
searchAge = do
    ...
    age   <- getNumber
    input <- readFile "databas.txt"
    putStrLn "\n Here are all the people that matches your search: \n"
    let people = parse input
        output = map personToString (filter (\p -> personAge p == age) people)
    in putStrLn (unlines output)
```

Comment: @dfeuer OK, OK, I will rollback / but please just keep your rep in check / while a bounty would be fine / this reputation should not be mine. / A new who knows more than me / would lighten up with joy and glee. / But if you think it's __that__ well done / your gift is certainly welcome.